# Should the "reset" option be a button or a link in crm?

Tags: website-design, forms, hyperlinks, button

I'm having to make the page as it was in the initial state, and this includes having a form reset link or button.

Should the reset be a button or a link?

Comment: See http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/5493/button-vs-link. I'm not clear why a reset function specifically matters.

Comment: @MichaelZuschlag it's a bit different; that question is generally correct but it's often the case in web apps that making an uncommon/dangerous secondary action a link to reduce emphasis and accidental clicking

Answer (score 1):

Do you really need a reset option? Is it deleting a draft or just restarting a form? Reset form buttons are pretty universally useless and famous for their frustrating consequences when you press them on accident. See [Reset/Cancel buttons considered harmful.](http://www.useit.com/alertbox/20000416.html)

If you do include one (once again, *really* make sure it's an important feature) absolutely make it a link and generally try to reduce it's visual weight. See [The visual weight of primary and secondary action buttons](http://uxmovement.com/buttons/the-visual-weight-of-primary-and-secondary-action-buttons/). Rarely used and dangerous controls, if included, should not appear to be the "default" action and should take a little extra effort to find and activate.

Comment: See also this Luke W classic: http://www.lukew.com/ff/entry.asp?571

Answer (score 0):

The question here isn't really clear without context, however I would encourage you to carry the same style throughout the entire CRM System.

If it were a button to continue I would always encourage buttons over link. Buttons can be styles to give a 3D effect of a physical button which can be pressed (and shadows changed) to encourage the user to "push" the button - however for a reset you don't want to encourage a reset unless the user NEEDS to - in that case they will go looking.

The advatage of a button on the other hand is user familiarity. A link should usually be a hyperlink to another place, as we've come to expect, and a button should run a command (Submit, Save, Reset, Delete)