# Call to action - Search box or button?

Tags: website-design, call-to-action

I have a tourism site where the main content is accommodation and activity listings (accommodation and activity providers have their own pages). The site has some other content in the form of articles.

The articles are usually about something specific relating to tourism in the area. I would like to include a call-to-action at the end of each of these articles linking through to a search page which displays relevant listings.

At the moment, I don't know whether it would be best to include a full search form at the end of every page which would perform a search and link to the results page. That would look like this:

[image: screenshot of a search form]

Or maybe it would be better just to have a button which links through to a search results page with pre-filled out search criteria. This might look like this:

[image: screenshot of an action button]

My question is which of these would provide the best call to action for the user after reading a relevant article?

If the latter is better, would anyone have any suggestions on how to make it clearer what the button does?

Comment: Well I wouldn't go with the second option, because the action of 'Places to Stay' isn't an action at all, it's a link. Therefore if you're going to go with that idea instead of a search form then I'd suggest replacing 'Places To Stay' button with a link. See this related post: http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/5493/what-are-the-differences-between-buttons-and-links

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second option I think doesn't sound really a call to action but a link to a section. Maybe changing the copy will help a bit more, but I think after reading an article only a button to continue (in another page) with relevant articles will be not a good idea.

The first option is better, but the user would have to fill in a form after reading an article to see more related articles. I guess you can help the user in that!

Maybe an solution can be showing the user a list of 3-5 related articles (don't let the user do all the work). And after that list you can include the call to action to find more of these "related articles". In this way the user can continue reading with the related articles suggested or go and search more articles.

Comment: Showing related listings is a great idea and then I could have a link to show "more like this". Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

The link/button you want to give at the end **should not be a small** little button or link because you want to gather the user's attention. A small button may be skipped by the user. So your first option is better.

But, since everyone is lazy, **fill out the form already for them!** You know all sorts of details from the article, prefill the form. That way there'd be no confusion about what the button does and it'll be big enough to make sure that user notices it. And in my opinion, more tempting to click.

Answer (score 1):

You should keep it a simple button at the bottom, but with more helpful text. For eg- you could have 'View Places to stay at while in "Name of location"'   , wherein, the name of location can get autofilled depending on the listing the user is looking at.